# Is every open set of a topology also closed?

Tags: general-topology

Hej,
last week I learned a bit about topologies. And by thinking about the subject I came across a problem. I think I can show that every open set in a topology is also closed, but I think that is not true for all topologies so there has to be an error in my calculation.

$(X,\tau)$ is topologic space.
The definition of closed is:
If $X\setminus\Phi$ is open, $\Phi$ is closed.
I know that I can build $X$ out of a union of open sets $O_i\in\tau$.
I assume that $O_i$ are the smallest possible open sets in $\tau$. That means that the intersection of all the smallest open sets is the empty set.
If it is not the empty set, that means that I have not taken the smallest open sets of $\tau$.
I know that because of the definition of a topology I can build open sets $O_j\in\tau$ with a union of open sets in $\tau$. $O_j=\cup O_i$.
Now I can remove one open set of this union by not adding it. And the union is still an open set. But that means that the removed open set is also closed.
Because I can do this with every open set of the topologic space and even can remove unions of open sets, that means every open set in $\tau$ is also closed.

I think that this is not true but I don't understand what I do wrong.
Can anybody help me?

Have a nice day,
Christoph

Comment: A topology in general does not  have smallest possible open sets. Consider $X = \mathbb R$ - what would be a smallest possible open set?

Comment: I agree with @PaulFrost . It will be good for you to think about the example of the real line, with its usual topology.  The basic open sets are the open intervals $(a,b)$.  Often, instead of just working with an abstract definition, it is useful to have one or more examples in mind.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your statement that you can remove a set from a union by not adding it is not correct in general:
if $O_i$, $i \in I$ is an indexed family of open sets and $i_0 \in I$, then:

$$
\left(\bigcup_{i \in I}O_i\right) \setminus O_{i_0} \neq \bigcup_{i \in I \setminus \{i_0\}}O_i$$

unless $O_{i_0} \cap O_i = \emptyset$ for all $i \neq i_0$.

For example, the real line $\Bbb{R}$ cannot be covered by 2 or more pairwise disjoint open sets. You will learn more about this when you get to study the notion of connectedness.

Comment: I know that I can only remove an open set $O_{i_0}$ by not adding it if the intersection with all the other sets is the empty set. But I did assume that I only used open sets $O_i$ which do not have an intersection with each other.
I think that I can assume that because in a topology, every finite intersection of open sets is an open set. So if the intersection of my sets $O_i$ is not empty, I can take smaller sets so that the intersection is empty.

Comment: Yes, but in general $X$ cannot be expressed as the union of a family of more than one pairwise disjoint open sets. Try it with $X = \Bbb{R}$.